# using replace in an update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update

I have what Im guessing I have a stupid question but I cant seem to get my update statement to work.
I have the following query.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(Text_col AS NVARCHAR(250)),'Vegetable oils','Refined Vegetable oils')AS 'DESCRIPTION', Text_col as 'ORIGINAL'
FROM Table1 
where  doc_id in (SELECT DOC_ID
FROM Table1
where Text_col like '%Vegetable oils%')
and FUNCTION_CODE = 'INGREDIENT'
```

This Returns me a table with two columns. It has 200+ rows. The DESCRIPTION column has the TEXT field with the updated text and the ORIGINAL has the original text so I could see all the changes side by side. I was happy with how it looked so I tried the following Query to update the tale to implement the changes.

```
begin transaction
UPDATE Table1 
Set Text_col = REPLACE(CAST(Text_col AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'Vegetable oils','Refined Vegetable oils')
WHERE  doc_id in(SELECT DOC_ID
FROM Table1
WHERE Text_col like '%Vegetable oils%')
and function_code = 'INGREDIENT DEC
```

The Query runs without error but updates 0 rows. For the life of me I can't spot why it wont update the 200+ rows that appear in the above SELECT statement.

Im running this on SQL 2012 Management studio as well if that is important.

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `begin transaction` or ending the transaction.

Comment: Try this : put that select statement above and below of update statement and analyze the result before and after.

Comment: I tried that there. the order of the rows changes slightly but the content remains the same.

Comment: There is a double space in vegetable oils in your update statement, was this an error when typing the question or is it present in the query?

Comment: Sorry this was an error while typing.

Comment: thanks, is there a character limit on the text_col column that the result would not fit in?

Comment: in the design view it has navchar(max) so I take for that there is no limit other than the maxium limit that could apply?

Comment: If the update and the subselect are hitting the same table there is no need to use a subselect here. Also, the where predicates in your select statement are different than the update. I also get the feeling that are using the text datatype? This whole thing could be greatly simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure your entire update could be simplified to this.

```
UPDATE Table1 
Set Text_col = REPLACE(CAST(Text_col AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'Vegetable oils','Refined Vegetable oils')
where FUNCTION_CODE = 'INGREDIENT'
```

There really is no need to limit the update since it is going to have to scan the table anyway and the subselect to pull doc_id is just adding extra work.

Comment: what about the FUNCTION_CODE <> 'INGREDIENT' rows?

Comment: Thanks @Caleth. I added that where predicate.